# Flagging with If condition

Tags: if-statement, sas

I got following flagging issue:

```
%let max = 5;
%macro target_years(table);
    data test ;
        set work.&table;
        %do i=1 %to &max;
            %if i = &max %then %do;
            %end;
            %else %do;
                "&&Zieljahre&i.._ZZ"n = 1-(1+("&&Zieljahre&i.._BP_Garantiestand"n-"&&Zieljahre&i.._BP_Ziel_Garantiestand"n)/"&&Zieljahre&i.._BP_Ziel_Garantiestand"n);
                %let x = "&&Zieljahre&i.._ZZ"n;         
                /*ZZ flag erstellen */
                    %if &x > 0 %then %do;
                    
                    "&&Zieljahre&i.._ZZ_flag"n = '+';
                    %end;
                    %else %do;
                    "&&Zieljahre&i.._ZZ_flag"n = '-';
                    %end;                       
            %end;
                    
        %end;
    run;
%mend;

%target_years(Kosten_temp)
```

Somehow all records are flagged with '-', the if condition with x doesn't work.

Can someone help me?

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Ben

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm using SAS.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't know what the macro-variables `max`, `x` resolve to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to mixing macro logic and data step logic.

You set the macro variable X to a string that starts with a `"` and then test if it is larger than the string `0`. So that test is always going to be false since `"` comes before `0`.

You probably want an actual IF statement there so you can test the value of the variable the previously generated SAS statement calculated.

```
%let max = 5;
%macro target_years(table);
%local i name ;
data test ;
  set work.&table;
%do i=1 %to &max-1;
  %let name = "&&Zieljahre&i.._ZZ"n;         
  &name = 1-(1+("&&Zieljahre&i.._BP_Garantiestand"n-"&&Zieljahre&i.._BP_Ziel_Garantiestand"n)/"&&Zieljahre&i.._BP_Ziel_Garantiestand"n);
/*ZZ flag erstellen */
  if &name > 0 then do;
    "&&Zieljahre&i.._ZZ_flag"n = '+';
  end;
  else do;
    "&&Zieljahre&i.._ZZ_flag"n = '-';
  end;                       
%end;
run;
%mend;
```